# Is there a way to pass a webelement as a parameter?

Tags: java, selenium, parameters, findby

I am building three test cases with a page object that contains three ID locators. I am wondering if I can pass a locator to a single method for all three cases.

Page Object:

```
public class SomeClass {

    @FindBy(how=How.CSS, using="label[for='yes']")
    private WebElement yes;

    @FindBy(how=How.CSS, using="label[for='maybe']")
    private WebElement maybe;

    @FindBy(how=How.CSS, using="label[for='no']")
    private WebElement no;

    public SomeClass(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

    public SomeClass clicksButtons() {
        *some locator*.click();
        return new someClass(this.driver);
    }
}
```

Test Case:

```
public class SomeTest {
    
    @Test
    public void willClickAButton() {
        
        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass(this.getDriver());

        SomeClass.clicksButtons();

        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
```

I would like to pass a parameter (yes, maybe, or no) into the clicksButtons method so that I can reuse the method in the other two test cases without have to hardcode it. I've searched Google and couldn't find a clear answer.

Comment: The scope of `WebElement yes` is private, they won't be available to other classes or packages. If `SomeClass` and `SomeTest` both are in similar package, please use protected scope.

Comment: I made the change.

Comment: Both classes are in same package or different package ?

Comment: They're in the same package.

Comment: Okay can you share clickButtons method code as well ?

Comment: I've added the ```protected``` modifier to ```clicksbuttons()```

Comment: @cruisepandey I found the answer and posted it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in Selenium Testing Tools Cookbook 2nd edition.

```
    public void select(String label) {

//I found the buttons by class and stored them in a List<>. In my case there were 3.
        List<WebElement> like = this.driver.findElements(By.className("custom-control-label"));
        
//iterate the buttons contained in the List<>
        for(WebElement button : like) 
        {
//if the button's "for" attribute contains the given label...
            if (button.getAttribute("for").equals(label)) 
            {
//...and if it is not selected...
                if (!button.isSelected()) 
                {
//click the button, according to the label
                    button.click();
                }
            }
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
public SomeClass clicksButtons() {
        *some locator*.click();
        return new someClass(this.driver);
    }
```

should be:

```
public SomeClass clicksButtons(WebElemenet ele) {
        ele.click();
        return new someClass(this.driver);
    }
```

and call this method like this:

```
SomeClass.clicksButtons(pass a webelement here);
```